# DNS when using split VPN on Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, dns

I'm using split-VPN on Windows XP as shown in:

[VPN: Does all traffic get routed through the VPN when I am logged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/136214/vpn-does-all-traffic-get-routed-through-the-vpn-when-i-am-logged-in)

My question is: how do I find out where DNS requests go? If I type an address (like www.google.com) into my browser, which of the two network interfaces resolves it? My hosts file has only one entry for localhost.

EDIT: Even if the VPN client is not running, I seem to be able to do an nslookup on "internalserver" which is not an internet hostname, but a private one that exists only inside the VPN network. Where might this be coming from? Does Windows cache DNS lookups somewhere? Where?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user1>nslookup internalserver
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.1.1: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.companyserver.com
Addresses:  xx.xx.xxx.xx, xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

Comment: One simple way would be to use a `tracert` and see where the connection goes through.  Then after that you would just need to figure out what the connection it goes through is pointing to for a DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

You can see what DNS server replies by opening a command prompt and typing nslookup www.google.com This should show the IP of the DNS that resolves www.google.com

My system reports as follows and indicates I am using the OpenDNS server 
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Address:  67.215.65.132

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but am not quite sure how to interpret the results. I pasted the results above in my questions as an edit. Any ideas?